# How to randomly re-insert an element in an array efficiently

Tags: java, arrays, random, insert

Suppose we have an integer array `int[] A = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}`.

Suppose we wanted to pick some random integer from `A`, and re-insert it somewhere else in the array randomly, like so:

First take some `int number = A[random.nextInt(A.length)]`

Suppose we randomly select `5`, and then re-insert it randomly between `7` and `8`, so that `A` becomes `{1,2,3,4,6,7,5,8,9}`.

Now, we can obviously do this re-insertion by creating some temporary variable `int temp = 5`, shifting the subarray `{6,7}` to the left, and then re-inserting `5` into the index that was occupied by `7` previously. But is there a more efficient way of doing this without shifting some subarray (and without changing to another data structure like linked list)? Because clearly we have some worst case scenario of `O(n)` where we randomly select `A[0]` and then have to insert it into `A[A.length]`, requiring all elements in the array to be shifted, which I'd prefer not to have to do.

Comment: You could have a look into [System::arraycopy](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy(java.lang.Object,%20int,%20java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int)) which can take `src` and `dest` as the same array.

Comment: "But is there a more efficient way of doing this without shifting some subarray (and without changing to another data structure like linked list)?" -- no. Arrays are exposed to you, the Java developer, as contiguous. So you're looking at O(n) worst case.

Answer (score 0):

Haven't done a lot of testing with this, but here's a quick sketch of a solution.

```
/**
 * Shifts the element of the given {@code array} presently at index {@code fromIndex} to
 * {@code toIndex}.
 * 
 * @param array     the array whose elements should be shifted
 * @param fromIndex the current index of the element to shift
 * @param toIndex   the destination index of the element to shift
 */
public static void shift(final Object array,
                         final int fromIndex,
                         final int toIndex) {
    if (fromIndex == toIndex) {
        return;
    }

    final Object atIndex = Array.get(array, fromIndex);

    if (toIndex > fromIndex) {
        System.arraycopy(array, fromIndex + 1, array, fromIndex, toIndex - fromIndex);
    } else {
        System.arraycopy(array, toIndex, array, toIndex + 1, fromIndex - toIndex);
    }

    Array.set(array, toIndex, atIndex);
}
```

While the *general* approach is pretty much what you describe, I suspect the performance of `System.arraycopy` is better than (almost) anything else you're going to get for this.  I could be very wrong though.